# Assign dummy value to whole group if at least one value in the group satisfies condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Specifically, I want to have a dummy variable for whether there is a missing value for a certain group.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
id    cash   dummy_missing
1     5      0
1     5      0
1     5      0
2     2      0
2     NaN    1
```

And it should look like this:

```
id    cash    dummy_missing
1     5      0
1     6      0
1     7      0
2     2      1
2     NaN    1
```

Thank you

Comment: You could probably do this in your SQL query to save post-processing.

Comment: Thank you, I have never worked with SQL, but I read about it today and figured it might be usefull which is why I included it into the tags, but I don't know what it means what you said.

Comment: If you're not actually using SQL to fetch this data, then ignore that comment, but you should also remove the tag from your question.

Comment: I've included it because I would've appreciated an answer using SQL too since I am open to learning how to use it. But an answer without SQL is fine too. If this is a wrong use of tags please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check where there are `NaNs` with `isna`, `groupby` the `id` and transform with `any`:

```
df['dummy_missing'] = df.cash.isna().groupby(df['id']).transform('any').view('i1')
```

---

```
print(df)
   id  cash  dummy_missing
0   1   5.0              0
1   1   5.0              0
2   1   5.0              0
3   2   2.0              1
4   2   NaN              1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test `id` with if `cash` values are missing and last convert boolean mask to integers for map `True, False` to `1,0`:

```
df['dummy_missing'] = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df.cash.isna(), 'id']).astype(int)
print (df)
   id  cash  dummy_missing
0   1   5.0              0
1   1   5.0              0
2   1   5.0              0
3   2   2.0              1
4   2   NaN              1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tested the speed of your answer versus that of yatu and yatu's answer is approximately 40% faster. Which is why I've accepted his answer.

Comment: @Olivier - Hmmm, are you sure? I guess not groupby solution should be faster.

Comment: @Olivier - It was tested in real data? How many real groups? How many rows? What is percentage of groups with missing values?

Comment: yes with real data, 8134 real groups, 1.455.223 rows, approximately 99.67% of groups have a missing value.

Comment: @Olivier - OK, thanks. I guess it is faster because many missing values.

Comment: Sorry actually I changed both you guys's code, I changed df.cash.isna() into df['cash'].isnull() maybe that made the difference? because I checked with a different variable with only 34.82% of groups with a missing variable and Yatu's is still faster.

Comment: @Olivier - I think not.